# jQuery Mobile in a large page

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I'm converting a legacy application to be mobile friendly and using jQuery Mobile. So far so good until I found this large page (2MB) where browser hangs when it loads. If I remove the jQuery Mobile references from the page, it loads without a problem.

So I'm guessing it hangs when it re-write the DOM with jQuery Mobile styles. But most of the controls (80%) are "display:none;" at the page load; Is there a way to jQuery Mobilize only the controls that are visible at the page load?

This is a badly designed page anyway and can't be rewritten to have a smaller size page now; because it will affect a lot of other places and the deadlines are too aggressive.

Please give your ideas on how to handle this.

Comment: Are you using a webView or android default browser to load the page?

Comment: This even fails in the desktop. Takes a long time to load. (to answer your question it's both Android (default/chrome) and iPhone

Comment: Anyone knows why this question is down-voted?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
data-role="none"
```

Find more about this in my other **[ANSWER](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, just search for chapter **Methods of markup enhancement prevention**. You will also find live **`jsFiddle`** example.

Comment: I tried using the data-role="none" to the divs that contain other controls? But didn't work. Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: data-role="none" will work only on that element, all child elements will stay the same. You will need to apply this to every possible element. This is not that good solution, unfortunately it is only one that can change single element in jQM. All other solutions work on whole page level, or on level of header/footer/content.

Comment: thanks make sense! 1 more question; In a latter js code how(if possible) manually put JQM styling? (for a click event may be)

Comment: yes. I was thinking put data-role"none" for all the "display:none" controls & then, at the time those become "display:block" call that js code to put the JQM stylings as well?

Comment: You will first need to remove data-role="none" they you will need to use this on your page object: $('#page-id').trigger('pagecreate'); or $('#page-id').trigger('create'); if you want to style only content div. Read more about this in a link I posted in my answer. You will also find examples.